# Joomla 3.8 replacing old source code in my template index.php

Tags: php, joomla

I have an issue with my joomla website.

My code in index.php is replaced with old code after 5 to 10 minutes.

```
/joomla/templates/mytemplate/index.php
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  Please post all Joomla questions in the dedicated community.

Comment: Please add a link here once you post on the Joomla stack exchange, I'm curious